# win32pdh.EnumObjectItems call error

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm running Python 2.7 in Windows 7, with `pywin32-216-win32-py2.7` installed. I'm running the following code, and it runs fine on one computer but outputs an error on another (both Win7, Py2.7, same pywin library).

Error message:

> File "C:\Energy\Support Sheets\Kill Excel.py", line 9, in GetProcessID
>       items, instances = win32pdh.EnumObjectItems( None, None, object, win32pdh.PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD )
>   error: (-1073738824, 'EnumObjectItems for buffer size', 'The specified object was not found on the computer.')

Full code:

```
import win32api, win32con
import win32pdh
import os
import signal
import time

def GetProcessID( name ) :
    object = "Process"
    items, instances = win32pdh.EnumObjectItems( None, None, object, win32pdh.PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD )
    val = None
    if name in instances :
        hq = win32pdh.OpenQuery()
        hcs = [ ]
        item = "ID Process"
        path = win32pdh.MakeCounterPath( ( None, object, name, None, 0, item ) )
        hcs.append( win32pdh.AddCounter( hq, path ) )
        win32pdh.CollectQueryData( hq )
        time.sleep( 0.01 )
        win32pdh.CollectQueryData( hq )

        for hc in hcs:
            type, val = win32pdh.GetFormattedCounterValue( hc, win32pdh.PDH_FMT_LONG )
            win32pdh.RemoveCounter( hc )
        win32pdh.CloseQuery( hq )
        return val

def Kill_Process_pid(pid):
  handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, pid) #get process handle
  win32api.TerminateProcess(handle, -1) #kill by handle
  win32api.CloseHandle(handle)        #close api

def Kill_Process(name):
    pid = GetProcessID(name)
    if pid:
        try:
            Kill_Process_pid(pid)
            return True
        except:
            pass
    else:
        return False

# MAIN FUNCTION
print 'Killing Excel instances...',
while Kill_Process('EXCEL'):
   time.sleep(0.2)
print 'Done!'
```

Comment: Is your locale English?  If not, the object names may be spelled differently.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when the Process performance counter was disabled - apparently this can just happen.  There are instructions [here](https://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/03/05/two-minute-drill-disabled-performance-counters-and-exctrlst-exe.aspx?Redirected=true) for how to re-enable the counters.  If you can't install software on the machine, you can run regedit and search for keys called "Disable Performance Counters" and delete them.

After that, you may need to run "lodctr /R" on a cmd shell as Administrator to reload the performance counters before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Manually rebuilding the performance counters solved my issue, you can use the following steps to manually rebuild and resync the performance counters with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)

Rebuild the counters:

```
cd c:\windows\system32
lodctr /R
cd c:\windows\sysWOW64
lodctr /R
```

Resync the counters with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI):

```
WINMGMT.EXE /RESYNCPERF
```